# Zoom limit and rightOffset with fixRightEdge

Tags: lightweight-charts

I have a chart (photo 1), I want to limit the zoom limit for the user so that at maximum zoom
the result was as in photo 1, now as in photo 2. The option with setting fixRightEdge: true is not suitable. in this case rightOffset: 10 does not work and the graph is too close to the right side (can this be changed?)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4M3J.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI5NC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Within the [TimeScale options](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions), you can have a look at the following:

- fixLeftEdge
- fixRightEdge

Additionally, the [TimeScaleApi](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi) has many methods for controlling the visible range of the chart.

You could also look into adding [Whitespace data](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/WhitespaceData) to the end of the series if you want to leave space on the right side of the plot. Whitespace data is a datapoint with a `time` but no `value`.

Comment: If fixRightEdge: true is set, then rightOffset: 20 doesn't work. How to make it work? 
Perhaps this can be changed in the lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js file itself?